# "export '__platform_browser_private__' was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, node-modules

I am developing an angular application. 
Getting an error in ERROR in `./node_modules/@angular/http/src/backends/xhr_backend.js 204:40-68` while i run : `ng serve`

> "export '**platform_browser_private**' was not found in
>   '@angular/platform-browser'

I comment out : `import { __platform_browser_private__ } from '@angular/platform-browser'`;
in `xhr_backends.js` file

I am using angular 8.

`app.module.ts` file:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';
import { NavbarModule } from './shared/navbar/navbar.module';
import { SidebarModule } from './sidebar/sidebar.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {ModalModule} from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

import { AdminLayoutComponent } from './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.component';
import { LoginpageComponent } from './loginpage/loginpage.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { JsonfetchComponent } from './jsonfetch/jsonfetch.component';
import { BreezeBridgeHttpClientModule } from 'breeze-bridge2-angular';
import {FacebookModule} from "ngx-facebook";
import {UrlPermission} from "./urlPermission/url.permission";
import { HttpService } from "./services/http.service"
import { AccountService } from "./services/account.service";
//import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import {platformBrowser} from "../../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser"


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    //LoginpageComponent,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NavbarModule,
    SidebarModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserModule,
    //platformBrowserDynamic
    BreezeBridgeHttpClientModule,
  //  HttpModule,
    FacebookModule.forRoot(),


  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AdminLayoutComponent,
    LoginpageComponent,
    JsonfetchComponent,
  ],

  providers: [UrlPermission, AccountService, HttpService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports:[BrowserModule]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

`package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "lbd-free-angular-cli",
  "version": "1.4.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "8.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/schematics": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "@ngui/map": "0.30.3",
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.30.13",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.27.13",
    "angular-modal-service": "^0.15.3",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.0",
    "arrive": "2.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "bootstrap-notify": "3.1.3",
    "breeze-bridge-angular": "^4.0.2",
    "breeze-bridge2-angular": "^1.1.0",
    "breeze-client": "^1.7.2",
    "chartist": "0.11.0",
    "core-js": "2.5.7",
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "flatpickr": "^4.6.2",
    "googleapis": "33.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "igniteui-angular": "^8.0.5",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jszip": "^3.2.2",
    "modclean": "^3.0.0-beta.1",
    "ng2-opd-popup": "^1.1.21",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^4.3.0",
    "ngx-facebook": "^2.4.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
    "rxjs": "6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.3.2",
    "sails": "^1.2.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.8",
    "@types/node": "10.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "igniteui-cli": "^4.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "3.2.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.3.1",
    "protractor": "5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "7.0.1",
    "tslint": "5.11.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when upgrading my @angular/cli from 6.x to 8.x.

When I ran `npm i` i noticed the following warning

> npm WARN deprecated @angular/http@2.4.10: Switch to @angular/common/http - see https://angular.io/guide/http

I believe you're still trying to `import from '@angular/http'` somewhere in your application.

In my case after updating my `app.module.ts`

from

`import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";`

to

`import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';`

as you've already done, I also updated my `web.service.ts`

from

`import { Http } from '@angular/http';`

to

`import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`

and it solved my problem.

Also, make sure to have your `BrowserModule` imported before your `HttpClientModule` as mentioned in https://angular.io/guide/http

> @NgModule({
>     imports: [
>       BrowserModule,
>       // import HttpClientModule after BrowserModule.
>       HttpClientModule,
>     ],

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably your auto-import failed. Try changing:

```
import {platformBrowser} from "../../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser"
```

in

```
import {platformBrowser} from "@angular/platform-browser"
```

Answer (score -1):

i think this is not related to angular-ssr

You need to run

npm install --save @angular/platform-browser